# Error 13 en tiempo de ejecución en formulario en excel

Tags: excel, vba

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, llevo un par de días con ello, tengo un formulario en excel, en cual en un textbox se introduce un id y al hacer click en un botón, aparece el nombre en otro textbox y luego se agrega a la tabla de excel.
Pues bien, cuando introduzco un id de 5 dígitos no hay problemna, pero si introduzco un id de de menos de 5 dígitos da el error 13.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Cells(Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row + 1, 2) = Val(TextBox1)
    
    Dim idempleado As String
    Dim Nombre As String
    
      
    idempleado = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Nombre = Application.VLookup(idempleado, Sheets("hoja1").Range("a2:K10458"), 5, 0)
   
    UserForm1.TextBox4.Text = Nombre

End sub
```

Gracias

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que tu VLOOKUP no encuentra el id de menos de 5 dígitos, y eso genera el error. ¿Te has asegurado que existe dicho id? ¿Estás trabajando con números o con textos? Excel diferencia entre números y textos.

Comment: Si el id existe, son sólo números, cuando introduzco el id de 5 dígitos me sale el nombre correctamente , pero luego no sé qué pasa pero i pongo el id de 4 dígitos, me sale el error 13. No sé qué pùede ser, he probado varios cambios, pero sigue saliendo el dichoso error.

Comment: Tu variable `idempleado` está declarada como string, así que está buscando textos, no números. Deberías también asegurarte que las celdas están con el formato correcto. Y que no haya duplicados.  ¿Puedes colgar un ejemplo de tus datos?

Answer (score 1):

No se especifica, pero seguramente el error se da en la linea del VLookup, la cuestión es que el error "no coinciden los tipos", en el caso de esa función, se da cuando el dato buscado no se encuentra, por lo que si deberías manejar el error de alguna manera, puede ser por ejemplo con On Error GoTo.

De cualquier manera, hay varias cosas que pueden salir mal con ese código, por ejemplo, si el tipo de dato buscado no coincide con el tipo de dato de la columna A, entonces VLookup no lo encontrara y te dará ese error.

Ademas, es posible que algunos datos de la columna A tengan espacios al inicio o fina, igual con el dato capturado en el textbox.

Me parece que en este caso seria mejor hacer la búsqueda con un ciclo `For Each`, de ese modo puedes controlar el tipo de dato que se busca, es decir, dinamicamente puedes convertirlo al tipo deseado, de tal forma que en todo momento se compare el mismo tipo durante la iteracion.

Puedes sustituir la linea del VLookup por algo como esto.

```
Dim rng As Range, r As Range
Set rng = Sheets("hoja1").Range("A1:A10458")

For Each r In rng
    If Trim(r.Text) = Trim(idempleado) Then
        Nombre = r.Offset(0, 4)
        Exit For
    End If
Next r
```

`r` representa la celda de la columna A que en ese momento esta en la iteracion, el `.Text` convierte ese dato a texto, esto para que coincida con el tipo del dato buscado "idempleado".

El `Trim` elimina los espacio al inicio y final, eso te asegura que se haga bien la comparación, aunque el dato de la columna A este mal registrado (con espacios) o el dato capturado en el textbox también este mal capturado.

También podrías ejecutar un proceso que elimine los espacios en blanco al inicio y final de cada registro de la columna A, esto para que en la tabla no haya datos mal registrados.

En caso de que el dato buscado sea texto en lugar de números, es posible que también que haya diferencia por las mayusculas y minusculas, eso se puede solucionar cambiando una de las lineas en el for.

En lugar de esto:

```
If Trim(r.Text) = Trim(idempleado) Then
```

Tendrías esto:

```
If LCase(Trim(r.Text)) = LCase(Trim(idempleado)) Then
```

Eso convierte a minúsculas cada dato de comparación en la iteracion, también el dato buscado.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a todos.

AL final, como bien habéis indicado, no encontraba el id, y era porque no contaba en que los id de menos de 5 dígitos tenían un 0 delante y en el textbox no estaba poniendo el 0, así que resuelto.

Gracias